# How to improve database design and ER diagram? What should I do with "boolean" fields?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, diagram

I'm learning SQL and I found a nice exercise (without an answer) so I don't have any hints on whether I am right or not and that's why I'm here.

**Design a Computer store database using an ER diagram:**

- The store sells printers & computers
- Some of the computers are laptops
- Each printer model has one manufacturer
- Each computer model may have more than one manufacturer
- Some manufacturers make both printers & computers
- Some of the printers print color, some black and white
- Each computer must have information on: Processor speed, RAM, HDD
  space.
- The computers that have CD drivers must have information on the CD
  driver's speed
- All the laptops should have information on their screen size
- Computers of the same model may differ in hardware (and price
  accordingly)

First, I tried to make an *ER diagram* but in the middle of the process I got confused.

For example,
**Some of the computers are laptops**:

Should I add a field (attribute) to the `Computer` object which is kind of a boolean field which determines whether the computer is a laptop or not? I don't get it.

Because later on, there is a need to
**All the laptops should have information on their screen size**
but in this case, which means I need to add a `Laptop` object as well, how can I connect between both the objects and claim that one **might** be the other object.. I don't get it.

**Some of the printers print color, some black and white**:

how can I do it in the diagram and later on in the database?

Another "kind of boolean" field is the **Some manufacturers make both printers & computers**.
Again, as in my first question, a manufacturer can be for both printers and computers and maybe not. Should I make an entire different object like I did in the diagram below, for each manufacturer?
How can I know later on in the database, if a manufacturer is for both printers and computers?

When i'm done, the next step is to write a SQL script to build this whole computer store database.

This is what I accomplished so far:

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia has a good article about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  Read the article and then read one of the books listed in the further reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens are online free in pdf & html.  Ask 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question about where you are 1st stuck.